# Uncaught TypeError: this.updateShelf is not a function

Tags: reactjs

So I have a small start React project...

I moved a method from a component into the top App component, now when I call another method within the main app component it says it does not exist, which is very confusing to me.

```
selectStateUpdate(book,shelf) {
  console.log("Sel"+JSON.stringify(book)+shelf)
  this.updateShelf(book, shelf);

}
updateShelf = (book, shelf) => {
  console.log("Updating shelf")
  BooksAPI.update(book, shelf)
  .then(() => BooksAPI.getAll())
  .then((books) => {
    this.setState({books})
  })
}
```

Above you can see that i'm trying to call updateShelf via this.updateShelf.  For full context see [App.js](https://github.com/robineyre29/reactnd-project-myreads-starter/blob/master/src/App.js)

When running the project I get following error in console when this function tries to run..

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.updateShelf is not a function
    at Object.selectStateUpdate [as updateSelect] (App.js:21)
```

For full context project can be viewed [here.](https://github.com/robineyre29/reactnd-project-myreads-starter)

Any help much appreciated, or if you need any clarification please ask.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times

***this. is not a function error***

happens due to using "this" in the wrong context so you can do one of these solutions. At the place, you invoke selectStateUpdate you can do this

```
this.selectStateUpdate(book,shelf).bind(this);
```

Or use this syntax

```
selectStateUpdate = (book, shelf) => {
  console.log("Sel" + JSON.stringify(book) + shelf);
  this.updateShelf(book, shelf);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `selectStateUpdate(book,shelf)` to `selectStateUpdate = (book,shelf) => {}`.

Hope this will help!